# How replace tabs with comma after 3rd tab position in a file

Tags: text-processing, aix

I have tab separated text file, the number of fields is not the same for every record. But I want to replace all tabs with commas after 3rd tab in the file.

### Input

```
100 Apple COOK USA EUROPE CHINA
200 Micro BIIL UK INDIA
300 Saums Chul SK
```

### Required out put:

```
100 Apple COOK USA,EUROPE,CHINA
200 Micro BIIL UK,INDIA
300 Saums Chul SK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk  'BEGIN{OFS=IFS="      ";}{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){$4=$4","$i;} print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
```

Output for your case will be:

```
100 Apple   COOK    USA,EUROPE,CHINA
200 Micro   BIIL    UK,INDIA
300 Saums   Chul    SK
```

The awk command will read line by line from file. Now it will print first second third word as it is but after fourth word it will concat them with comma.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Command returning expected output. Could you please explain how it is working.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
sed -i 's#\t#,#4g' file


100 Apple   COOK    USA,EUROPE,CHINA
200 Micro   BIIL    UK,INDIA
300 Saums   Chul    SK
```

- `4g` to replace the tab with a comma from 4th occurrence in each line.

Comment: It is not working, getting error sed -i is illegal option.

Comment: @chavakumar which distro are u using? is it Mac?

Comment: This answer is very specific to GNU sed. If you're on a Mac, install GNU sed with Homebrew: https://brew.sh/

Comment: I had tried to execute this command on AIX server. version is 7.1.0.0